# Is there a linux program for mouse stroke recognition?

Tags: linux, mouse

Is there a mouse stroke recognition software for linux? I need one that I can press a mouse button, and drag, and then it will open a program, or something like that.

Is there any programs out there for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a program that is called [easystroke](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easystroke/) recognition software. You can customize it for whatever mouse button you want (like the middle, left, right, etc). It is very simple to use, and it works great.